# how to draw bitmap image using putimage function in c

Tags: c, bitmap, bmp

I'm dealing with machine embedded C language software and struggling to understand how to use 'putimage' function to load 'qrcode'image in c. What I've tried to do is put some image on the LCD panel screen on the machine and coudn't figure out how to use putimage function properly.

I've learned that 'putimage' function shows image data array which have gotten from 'getimage' function and two functions I've mentioned are used as below.

void putimage(int left, int top, void *bitmap, int op);

void getimage(int left, int top, int right, int bottom, void *bitmap) ;

Since it is said that bitmap files can be converted to hex format starting '0x42, 0x4D...', I've tried to put array which I've defined like 'char QRbuff[] = {'0x42, 0x4D,...,}' into '*bitmap' parameter while using 'putimage'fuction. but no image have been appeared.

If I defined BMPbuff[] as below ingnoring bitmap format(eg. 0x42, 0x4D), some dotted image is shown.

char BMPbuff[] = {30, 0, 30, 0, 0x18, 0x24, 0x42, 0x99, 0x99, 0x42, 0x24, 0x18} ;

I have no idea how it works. I guess bitmap format that has to do with putimage is not the format which starts with 0x42, 0x4D. Instead, it seems that the format start with size of image {30, 0, 30, 0...} which I don't know where it came from.

I would be so appreciated with any help how to define bitmap array in this case...

[image]
[image]

Comment: You're confusing the concept of bitmap images with the Microsoft Paintbrush File Format. Beyond that, there is no sufficient information to help you here, try to make an all black image using `0x00` or `0xFF`, then see how an array full of `0x80`s behaves etc...

Comment: aprreicated you're right I was confused. with your helpful advice I've changed source codes to 0xff or 0x00 but nothing changed. in fact it seems that it dots randomely which makes no sense. what else should I try in this case?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala and I added some pics of what I've tried.

Comment: The buffer is way too small for 30x30 bits, so there is going to be some garbage. You need at least 4 * 30 *bytes* in the array

Comment: thank you very much @AnttiHaapala I keep trying what you have told and got the result as I updated pics above. seems it works in a way. My question here is the exact format of array. for example how many first bytes are to be allocated to the size of image and so on. I still don't have any idea of how may bytes should be allocated to the 30*30 image and I don't even know how to set char array for image to be 30*30 size. like do I need to set the first 4 byte (30, 0, 30, 0)? if that so what exact rule or format should I refer to? Thank you again in advance.

Comment: As I said 30x30 image necessarily has at least 900 bits. Add some more to the array so that it is distinguishable from the garbage

Comment: by doing what you told me, I can see rectangler is getting darker. Is there any way that I can see how the format works...? like I asked earlier I have no idea how the rule or format works.. thanks again.

Comment: I have no idea either. You've got 100000 % more documentation than I have at my disposal

Comment: @Frank.lee - Are you using the [Borland Graphics Interface (BGI)](https://www.cs.colorado.edu/~main/cs1300/doc/bgi/index.html)?